# Firebase Firestore - Using ServerTimeStamp in a Custom Object in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore in my project and have created [Custom Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) to handle the incoming and outgoing data.  This works perfectly for my needs - with one exception.

I would like to set a serverTimestamp onto my objects.  I have read the docs and see that I can do this [like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp). The docs state that I can use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` in the `setData` and `updateData` calls, and shows the following example:

```
db.collection("objects").document("some-id").updateData([
    "lastUpdated": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
]) { err in
    ...
}
```

However, in my code, I pass the custom object into these functions, like this:

```
let city = City(name: "Los Angeles")
do {
    try db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(from: city)
} catch let error {
    print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
}
```

So, what I want is to add a new property to my custom class, which will do two things:

- When creating the data for the first time will set a serverTimestamp
- When fetching the data will store the timestamp as a date I can use.

What do I need to do to my custom class to make this happen?

```
public struct City: Codable {
    let name: String
    let createdAt: Date
}
```

THANK YOU in advance for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK I found the answer:

```
public struct City: Codable {
    let name: String
    @ServerTimestamp var createdAt: Timestamp?
}
```

Here, the createdAt is nil when I call `setData`.  The server will populate this with the server value, and then the next time I fetch the data from the server it will be populated with the written datetime (and never overwritten)

Comment: How do I add this to realm db? "@Persisted" gives error

Answer (score 0):

```
struct City: Codable {
    let createdAt: Double
    let nameCity: String
    init(name: String) {
       nameCity = name
       timestamp = FIRServerValue.timestamp()
        
    }
}
```

After this, you can call City(name: "Los Angeles"), and a timestamp will be created.

Comment: FIRServerValue not recognised for me.

Comment: otherwise you can use Date().timeIntervalSince1970

Comment: I posted the correct answer above.  Thanks for your help anyway.